# Upgraded to ubuntu studio 20.04 and lost all the extra video effects in Kdenlive and Openshot

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-studio, video-editor, kdenlive, openshot

When i upgraded to Ubuntu Studio 20.04, I lost all the weird video effects (like screen glitching, old Film effect, etc) that used to appear in Kdenlive and Openshot.
What package(s) am I missing?

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS had 3 years of supported life (*being a flavor*) which ended in 2023-April. See https://ubuntustudio.org/2020/04/ubuntu-studio-20-04-lts-released/ with special upgrade instructions for those upgrading from earlier releases (esp. 18.04) as 18.04 was **not** a LTS release for Ubuntu Studio.  Also note that Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS was the *end of the road* for upgrades as it was the last release using Xfce as the desktop.